# Help with calculation with derivatives.

Tags: derivatives

Ok, so this is probably a brain fart on my part, but anyway I have that $x=e^s$, and the second step of the following is unclear to me:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{ds}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dx}{ds}=x\frac{d}{dx}
\end{equation}
My question is why is $\frac{dx}{ds}=x$?

Comment: it is the chain rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because: $$\frac{{\rm d}\color{red}{x}}{{\rm d}s} = \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}s}(\color{red}{e^s}) = e^s = x.$$

Comment: Thanks! It's always the simple things screwing with me.

Comment: It can happen to anybody :P